# Get previous and next row from mysql based on rank

Tags: mysql

I use this mysql query to get rank by point. I need to get previous and next item by rank.

For example: item's rank is 99. At item page,  I want to show 100th, 101th, 98th and 97th items.

http://erincfirtina.com/apps/urdemo/track.php?tid=10

i need to do related tracks list

Here is my mysql query which get rank:

```
SELECT 
uo.*, 
( SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM tracks ui WHERE (ui.point, ui.id) >= (uo.point, uo.id) ) AS rank
FROM tracks uo WHERE id = 10
```

Comment: When you mean the 100th rank, does it mean rank coming from `( SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM tracks ui WHERE (ui.point, ui.id) >= (uo.point, uo.id) ) AS rank`? We'd better see the structure of the table to clarify

Comment: Further from @fedorqui's comment, you should put a [fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com) up with some of your data

Comment: here is the fiddleup link: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/86f3b/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never asked a question.

One thing I am observing is that you are using a table (uo) inside the subselect that isn't part of the subselect.

Maybe you are looking for:

```
SELECT  uo.*, COUNT(*) AS rank
FROM tracks ui, tracks uo 
WHERE (ui.point, ui.id) >= (uo.point, uo.id) 
  AND uo.id = 10;
```

Hard for me to test its accuracy with no idea of what your table looks like, or what your question actually is.

Comment: This query won't work, as you're mixing aggregates (`COUNT(*)`) with unaggregated fields.

Comment: Yeah, it needs a GROUP BY, but I have no way of knowing what to group by without more data from the OP.

Answer (score 0):

This query should work, although it will scale very badly.

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT 
    uo.*, 
    ( SELECT  COUNT(*) FROM tracks ui WHERE (ui.point, ui.id) >= (uo.point, uo.id) ) AS rank
    FROM tracks uo WHERE id = 10
) t
ORDER BY t.rank DESC
```